# Cannot delete file, change permissions or take ownership as admin

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, network-shares, nas

I have a Shuttle OmniNAS KD20 NAS that runs Samba. It's connected to my desktop that runs Windows 10. I mapped the NAS to Z:\ and access it with user named "OmniNAS\nasuser".

Here's the problem. I'm trying to clear off some old files that I saved with an older machine (no longer exists) but I'm getting the error "You need permission from Unix User\1000 to make changes to this file". Here's the file permissions:

[image]

So the first obvious problem is there is no listing for "nasuser". The second problem is that everyone only has read access. Thirdly, I have no idea what "Unix User\1000" is (domain is incorrect, should be "OmniNAS"). I never created it nor I am able to re-create this user now as OmniNAS complains it only contains digits (thanks for nothing Shuttle).

[image]

So I'm left off with a bunch of useless read-only permissions that I cannot modify.

The Shuttle OmniNAS doesn't have any a web interface where I could delete the files, and no longer has SSH access.

Any suggestions? Is there any way to "hack" the permissions or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The disk itself is configured as a Linux file system; if you access it directly from Windows rather than through the OmniNAS software, the files should show up as Unix User.

In Linux, files are stored under the user id number, not the user id name. The user name is assigned to the file by comparing the user id number against the passwd file. When a file is listed by number, that means no match was found in the passwd file.

Given that OmniNAS is intended to run as a cloud, it should carry its passwd file with it. This implies that the user was removed without removing the associated files.

My suggestion, unfortunately as someone who isn't familiar with OmniNAS - only with Linux and RAID, would be, access the OmniNAS as admin through the web interface, see if you can find the file that way, possibly in the "Storage" folder, and remove it there.